# Duplicate Results From Search Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-deployment

I have a search method and two models, restaurants and menus.In the menu search method, if I search for "chicken" it shows the closest restaurants near the location that sells meals with word chicken example "chicken sandwich" with the use of association. The problem is, if a restaurant sells multiple chicken meals the restaurant is rendered several times.I want to be able to show restaurants once and when the button is clicked a modal shows the meals with "chicken" in the name using a loop if there are multiple meals with chicken. I tried adding uniq & uniq(&:restaurant_id) in the ActiveRecord and also controller & also trying "DISTINCT" using sql but nothing.

[image: Example of problem]

Controller

```
def search_for_menus
    #@restaurant= Menu.restaurant.all
    @menus = Menu.search_for_menus(params)
  end
```

Menus Model

```
belongs_to :restaurant
  reverse_geocoded_by "restaurants.latitude", "restaurants.longitude"

  def self.search_for_menus(params)

    menus=Menu.where("dish LIKE ?", "%#{params[:dish]}%") if params[:dish].present?
    menus = menus.where("menus.price <=?",params[:max ])
    menus = menus.where("menus.price >=?",params[:min ])

    menus= menus.joins(:restaurant).near(params[:location],2)

   menus  
  end
end
```

Search Page HTML

```
    <% if @menus.present? %>
<%@menus.each do |menu| %>
    <br>
    <br>


<div id ="restaurants">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="thumbnail box-image">

            <%= link_to (image_tag (menu.restaurant.thumbnail.url(:medium))),restaurant_path(menu.restaurant),'data-no-turbolink' => true%>  

      <div class="caption">
        <h3 class="text-center"><%=menu.restaurant.name%></h3>

        <p class="text-center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary text-center" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-<%= menu.id %>">View Food</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>

          </div>

<div id="modal-<%= menu.id %>" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p><%= menu.dish %></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
      <p><%= menu.price %></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>



<%end%>



</div>




<%else%>

<p>no posts</p>

<%end%>
```

Comment: does that menu belong to more than 1 restaurant? As a note if `params[:dish]` is not present this will break completely.

Comment: each menu record belongs to a specific restaurant so Menu with id 1 belongs to restaurant id 33 & Menu with id 3 can belong to restaurant id 35.Thanks for the tip for the dish, will change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussing over chat, here's an update, thanks @David for the query.

Menu model:

```
  belongs_to :restaurant
  reverse_geocoded_by "restaurants.latitude", "restaurants.longitude"

  def self.search_for_restaurants(params)
    Restaurant.near(params[:location],2).
                         where(Menu.where("dish LIKE ?", "%#{params[:dish]}%").
                                    where("menus.price <=?",params[:max ])
                                    where("menus.price >=?",params[:min ]).exists)
  end
```

Put this in the restaurant model (here you are going to fetch all the matching menus for the view):

```
def search_for_matching_menus dish
  menus.where("dish LIKE ?", "%#{dish}%")
end
```

View (you have to adjust it to your needs, I just want you to understand the idea):

```
<% if @restaurants.present? %>
  <%@restaurants.each do |restaurant| %>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <div id ="restaurants">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="thumbnail box-image">
          <%= link_to (image_tag (restaurant.thumbnail.url(:medium))),restaurant_path(restaurant),'data-no-turbolink' => true%>  
          <div class="caption">
            <h3 class="text-center"><%=restaurant.name%></h3>
            <%= restaurant.search_for_matching_menus(@dish).each do |menu| %>
              <%= menu.id %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

And finally this has to go on the controller that calls the search, to forward the dish parameter:

```
@dish = params[:dish]
```

Comment: I'm thinking about it, could you please paste the SQL generated by this on you console? thanks

Comment: Please test it again with the updated code, sorry, it's kinda tricky because I can't run it. thanks! @user3110815

Comment: Understood, the updated code doesn't work "did you mean nearbys" error comes up then if I try nearbys I get a merge error. The sql for .distinct and .uniq seem to be the same. Then the page loads the right restaurants with the right ids.Here is the sql being rendered using .distinct and .uniq  [link](http://pastebin.com/maBQELXU)

Comment: Okay, just to make sure I'm understanding what you're doing here.
This method we are changing returns an array of menus, correct?
And what you are displaying, and trying to make unique, are the restaurants, am I right?
If yes, please post also the code that you are using to render for better understanding.@user3110815

Comment: Yes an array of menus are being chained then the last line is essentially returning menus.restaurant where the address of the restaurant is near the entered parameter.Updated the post to show the html.erb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116733/discussion-between-fabriciofreitag-and-user3110815).

Answer (score 2):

What you need to start with, I think, is the restaurants for which there exists a matching menu item.

```
restaurants = Restaurant.near(params[:location],2).
                         where(Menu.where("menus.restaurant_id = restaurants.id").
                                    where("dish LIKE ?", "%#{params[:dish]}%").
                                    where("menus.price <=?",params[:max ]).
                                    where("menus.price >=?",params[:min ]).exists)
```

This is guaranteed to return one row per restaurant.

You might want ILIKE for a case insensitive dish search, if your RDBMS supports it.

You can then list the appropriate menu items for the matching restaurants.

Comment: Thanks @David, I hope you don't mind that I used that query to update the post.

Comment: @David After doing some testing I found that some food searches gave restaurants that didn't sell the searched food and also when I increased the distance in the near method it shows more unrelated restaurants, it seems as if the where condition for ("dish LIKE ?", "%#{params[:dish]}%") isn't filtering unmatched results, is there any modification to the code that can possibly fix this?

Comment: Here is a link to the generated SQL from the server and from when I manually did it in the console [link](http://pastebin.com/ahvjrupL)

Comment: @user3110815 Ah yes, it was missing the critical join between the menus and restaurants tables.